# HTML5 cache: I'm really confused with this NETWORK section

Tags: html, caching, offlineapps

From what I understand, the NETWORK section contains the resources that ALWAYS need to be accessed via a network connection.

For my app, I have two main page: index.html and gallery.html

gallery.html is the one that references the manifest file and in this same manifest file I wrote the following:

```
NETWORK:
index.html
```

However if I visit index.html while online and then access it while offline I can see index.html.

So it seems to be loaded from the traditional cache (not the offline app one)

What's the point of this NETWORK section? It is really really confusing :(

Thanks for your time guys.
Cheers!

Comment: What browser are you using? ApplicationCache can be funky at the moment across different browsers/OS/device

Comment: I'm testing it with Firefox 5.01

Answer (score 0):

go to http://about:cache and see if index.html is in the Offline cache device. It's probably not.

Now with that being said, browser's will cache the crap out of your page. But if you were to go offline, then clear your cache, then try to access index.html; you would be out of luck. Gallery.html should load offline just fine after that.

I eventually just did this with my network section:

```
NETWORK:
*.*
```

So anything not listed above is a network resource. Although, this solution may not fit your needs.

Comment: I see that nothing is listed in the cache even though I have a popup asking me if I want to allow offline caching (and yes I allow it :D)

Comment: Chrome's logging for this is by far the best. Open up the console in chrome (inspect element... click console) and load the page. See if you get any errors listed there. Firefox/Safari just seem to ingore Application Cache errors

Answer (score 0):

good news: I recently spoke with Peter Lubbers, an HTML5 expert, and he explained to me the purpose of the NETWORK section.

First important thing to keep in mind is that all pages of your application should referenced the manifest file since not all user are going to enter your site via the same page.

Pages that reference the manifest are automatically cached in the manifest except if the page is listed in the NETWORK section.

Hope that helps :)